# Call stored procedrue with output parameter in php

Tags: php

How do I call stored procedure that have output parameter through php?

```
$user="root";
$password="";
$database="phppractice";
mysql_connect('localhost:3306',$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$result = 10;
$query="call VerifyUserNPass(" . $user . "," . $result . ");";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

It doesn't give the correct result .

Comment: By using ?> you are terminating the php processing. Also the mysql_ functions are deprecated and will be removed

Comment: Sorry I accidentally put it

Comment: result is the output parameter

Answer (score 3):

> **[CALL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html)**
>
> For programs written in a language that provides a MySQL interface,
>   **there is no native method for directly retrieving the results of OUT
>   or INOUT parameters from CALL statements.** To get the parameter values,
>   pass user-defined variables to the procedure in the CALL statement and
>   then execute a SELECT statement to produce a result set containing the
>   variable values. To handle an INOUT parameter, execute a statement
>   prior to the CALL that sets the corresponding user variable to the
>   value to be passed to the procedure.

Therefore you need to do it like this

```
mysql_connect('localhost:3306',$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($database, $link);

mysql_query("CALL VerifyUserNPass('$user', @result)", $link);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT @result result", $link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['result'];
mysql_free_result($result);
```

If result is an `INOUT` parameter then you need to set a value prior to SP call

```
mysql_query($link, "SET @result = 10");
```

*All error checks skipped intentionally for brevity*

Comment: very nice Answer.